# how to check if a specific key exists in json object using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have some json that looks like this....

```
{"errorMessage":"Items not found, please enter additional search criteria"}
```

This only gets returned when there is a server error. On other times where there are no server errors a json object with a json arrary in it is returned.

Inside my getJson method I want to write some jquery to check if the json returned contains a key "errorMessage" and if it does I want to get it's value. But I'm struggling to find the right way.

```
    $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {
            // need to do check here

            fnCallback(json);
        } );
```

Can someone give me a hand please? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, JSON is a text-based data-interchange format, it's not an object.

To check if a key exists in an object, you can use the `in` operator.

```
$.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (data) {
    if ('errorMessage' in data) {
        //there was an error
    }
});
```